# Overhead of nested synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

Consider the following 2 examples:

Example 1:

```
Class A {
    private final B b = new B();
    public synchronized void m1() {
        b.m2();
    }
}
Class B {
    public void m2() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Example 2:

```
Class A {
    B b = new B();
    public synchronized void m1() {
        b.m2();
    }
}
Class B {
    public synchronized void m2() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Assuming B.m2() is **only** called in A.m1(),
what's the cost of synchronizing B.m2() if it's already guarded by A.m1()? i.e. Does Example 2 add any overhead compared to Example 1? Does the JVM optimize Example 2 to make it look like Example 1?

Comment: It's not already guarded by A's m1. The synchronized in A makes sure that no other thread can call A.m1() without first getting the lock **on the A object**. But any thread having a reference to B can call B.m2() even if A is already calling it if B.m2() is not synchronized.

Comment: @JBNizet Assume no other thread can have a reference to B and that B is only used in A.m1().

Answer (score 1):

If you synchronize `m2`, there would be some overhead involved since when entering `m2` the thread would still have to acquire the lock on the `b` object (event if the lock would be always free).

The JVM ***might*** figure out the synchronization is redundant and optimize it (i.e. remove the `synchronized` from `m2`) if *escape analysis* in enabled. If the code would get optimized, there would be no performance difference. The optimizations that remove redundant synchronization are called *lock elision* or *lock coarsening*.

For more details on escape analysis please see the following [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis).